# How to save a movie made from pictures by OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I wrote a **Python** program with **OpenCV** that:

1. scans the folder with images
2. does some operations on them with respect to their order
3. returns a list **IMGs** of processed images

Now what I want to do, is to save the list **IMGs** of new pictures as a e.g. **.avi** movie. How to do such operation? I intentionally want to save pictures from a list after whole process of filtration etc.

```python
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

folder_name = 'trial1'
extension = '.bmp'
path = os.getcwd()

GB_kernel = (13,13)

""" List all .bmp images names from a folder """ 
def folder_content(folder_name, extension):

    dir_content = os.listdir(folder_name)
    folder_content_ext = []
    for file in dir_content:
        if file.endswith(extension):
            folder_content_ext.append(file)

    return folder_content_ext

IMG_names = folder_content(folder_name, extension)

""" Some OpenCV operations on images """
""" Loop over all images. Iterator i is important in the future """
IMGs = []
for i in range(len(IMG_names)):

    """ Define path to basic image """ 
    img = path + '\\' + folder_name + '\\' + IMG_names[i]
    """ read this image """ 
    image = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    """ some operation - gaussian blur """ 
    pre_filt = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, GB_kernel, 0)
    """ contain blurred img in a list """ 
    IMGs.append(pre_filt)

    cv2.imshow('Gaussian Blur', pre_filt)
    WKey = 1
    if cv2.waitKey(WKey) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

""" HOW?? """
save_list_of_matrix_as_movie(IMGs)
```

Thanks for any help and hints.

Comment: Quick question... do you have enough memory to hold all the images, or should you maybe write the processed frames back to disk and generate the video with `ffmpeg` afterwards?

Comment: Yes, I know that it is memory expensive, but for my task this method is safe. However, writing the frames to disc is nice tip, Than you.

Comment: You can use the VideoWriter() module and there is no reason to wait till the end, you could add the frames to the video as you process them.

Comment: The reason, why I want to contain the frames in a list and save them later as a movie is that, I am affraid that any other operation in a loop could make that the frame capture will be longer and I will loose the camera speed (e.g. in future). But yes, as long as I work only with images from file i can do it like you say. But yes, I want to have program for both cases (from file and real time capture). My fault, I gave an imprecise description of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""

Create video from images in a list.

Idea from:
http://tsaith.github.io/combine-images-into-a-video-with-python-3-and-opencv-3.html

"""

import os
import time
import cv2

folder_name = 'trial1'
extension = '.bmp'
video_file = 'out.avi'
path = os.getcwd()

GB_kernel = (13, 13)


# %%
def folder_content():
    """
    List all images names with given extension from a folder.
    """
    dir_content = os.listdir(folder_name)
    folder_content_ext = []
    for file in dir_content:
        if file.endswith(extension):
            folder_content_ext.append(file)

    return folder_content_ext


# %%
def img_2_matrix(img_names):
    """
    Some OpenCV operations on images
    Loop over all images. Iterator i is important in the future
    """
    imgs = []
    for i in range(len(img_names)):

        # Define path to basic image
        img = os.path.join(path, folder_name, img_names[i])
        # read this image
        image = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        # some operation - gaussian blur
        pre_filt = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, GB_kernel, 0)
        # contain blurred img in a list
        imgs.append(pre_filt)

        cv2.imshow('Gaussian Blur', pre_filt)
        wkey = 1
        if cv2.waitKey(wkey) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    return imgs


# %%
def save_list_of_matrix_as_movie(imgs):
    """

    """
    shape = (imgs[0].shape[1], imgs[0].shape[0])
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")  # XVID for avi, mp4v for mp4
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(video_file, fourcc, 20.0, shape, 0)

    print("\nHit 'q' to exit")
    for frame in imgs:
        pre_filt = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, GB_kernel, 0)
        out.write(pre_filt)  # Write out frame to video
        cv2.imshow("video", pre_filt)
        if(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord("q"):  # Hit `q` to exit
            break

    return out


# %%
def release(out):
    """
    Release everything if job is finished
    """
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    out.release()


# %%
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # %%
    TIC = time.time()

    # %%
    img_names = folder_content()
    imgs = img_2_matrix(img_names)
    out = save_list_of_matrix_as_movie(imgs)
    release(out)

    # %%
    print("Time elapsed: %0.2f s" % (time.time() - TIC))
```

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpfull, additionally, I found that the VideoWriter method wants col's and row's tuple, not row's and col's tuple... furthermore it wants also BGR image, not GRAYSCALE, so I must convert them. Maybe it was a bug in my code but after all those changes my program starts working.

Comment: If you don’t need grayscale, you can replace the instruction `image = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` with `image = cv2.imread(img)`.

Comment: No problem, thanks for remind, I'm quite newbie here. I will vote for it after I get 15 points of respect ;)